# Write Sql sub Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, subquery

I have following 3 tables(Organization, OrganizationAddress, Address).Each organizations has more than one address and one of them is primary.if an organization has primary address,I need to select the primary address else that column can be null or blank.

How can i write a sql sub query in mysql?.
Please help me,

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: no need of sub query, left join will work

Comment: table convention is wrong and table stu is also wrong

Comment: first select rows with Primary address, then those without it, and use  `UNION ALL` to get all in one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a `LEFT JOIN`

```
select a.orgid, b.orgaddressid, c.address
from organization a
left join organization_address b on a.orgid = b.orgid and b.isprimaryaddress = 'YES'
left join address c on b.orgaddressid = c.addressid
where a.orgid = 1;
```

Comment: @ Fabricator Thank you ..but not excepted result the result has duplication of organizaions

Comment: @edaklij, I put `isprimaryaddress = 'YES'` in the wrong place. can you try updated one?

Comment: Thanx Fabricato..Perfect !!!...One more doubt if i need to apply a where condition on organization  table,Where i can write that?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this. I think you need to use `LEFT JOIN` for both tables:

```
select 
   organization.orgid, 
   organization_address.orgaddressid, 
   address.address
from 
   organization
LEFT JOIN organization_address 
    ON organization_address.orgid = organization.orgid 
    AND organization_address.isprimaryaddress = 'YES'
LEFT JOIN address 
    ON organization_address.orgaddressid = address.addressid;
```

Answer (score 0):

A LEFT JOIN selects rows in the left table and matching rows in the right table if there are matching rows in the right table. If there aren't any matching rows in the right table the query will return NULL for the columns from the right table.

```
SELECT o.OrgId, oa.OrgaddressId, a.Address FROM Organization AS o 
LEFT JOIN 'Organization Address' AS oa ON oa.OrgId=o.OrgId 
LEFT JOIN Address AS a ON a.AddressId=oa.OrgAddressId
WHERE oa.IsPrimaryId='YES';
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub Query is slower then join query,  so i just inform to  you please ignore sub query

if you want to get this type of result you can use Left join

```
select a.orgid, b.orgaddressid, c.address
from organization a
left join organization_address b on a.orgid = b.orgid and b.isprimaryaddress = 'YES'
left join address c on b.orgaddressid = c.addressid
where a.orgid = 1;
```

Left join means

**returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.**

visit the Types of join in google you can get more idea